# Pointer to an array of cstrings declared dynamically

Tags: c++, pointers, char

```
char ** ptr = new char *[3];
ptr[0] = new char [5];
ptr[1] = new char [6];
ptr[2] = new char [7];

cout<<"Enter first array: ";
cin.getline(ptr[0], 5);
cin.getline(ptr[1], 6);
cin.getline(ptr[2], 7);
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    cout<<ptr+i<<endl;
}
for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    delete[] ptr[i];
}
```

When I run this code, it gives the following output:

```
    Enter first array: name
    0xf99c20
    0xf99c28
    0xf99c30
```

I actually wanted the user input printed out.

Could someone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: Err... Solution to?

Comment: You probably wanted to print `ptr[i]` which is same as `*(ptr+i)`. BTW, despite your last `delete[]..` in a loop, you still have a leak. Prefer `std::string` for your string needs and `std::vector<T>` for your array needs

Comment: 1. Solution to what??? 2. You need to `delete[] ptr` at the end of your code. 3. You may as well declare `char* ptr[3]` (instead of allocating it and deleting it). 4. There are much simpler, better and more correct ways of doing whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `ptr+i` is `char**`, not `char*`, so is just being printed as a pointer. To have it print as a string, use `ptr[i]`, which is a `char*`.

That said, use a `std::vector<std::string>`. Then you can use the [`string` version of `std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Then you avoid many possible problems with matching up `new` and `delete`, leaks, dealing with longer user input, dealing with a different number of lines of user input, etc.

---

Also, please reconsider your use of what are often considered bad practices: [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html) (those are links to explanations).

Comment: @MuhammadIbrahim if this is the solution to your problem you should accept the answer...

Answer (score 0):

you have logic misunderstanding of pointer concept when you print `ptr+i` it will give you the actual address locations of your inputs in the memory

to print the value of pointer you can use:

```
*(ptr+i)
```

or :

```
ptr[i]
```

also `getline (char* s, streamsize n );` max stream size of your inputs should be bigger because there is a null character `'\0'` at the end of each character sequences and newline character `'\n'` when you enter another input:

```
cin.getline(ptr[0], 10);
cin.getline(ptr[1], 10);
cin.getline(ptr[2], 10);
```

link to the solution:
https://ideone.com/maSOSs